# How do I make a trash icon clear a text area in java script?

Tags: javascript

For example I have here

```
<textarea id="clear"></textarea>
```

then instead of button onclick="(clear)" i want it to be a trash icon.

Javascript

```
function clear(){
     document.getElementById('clear').value = "";
}
```

Comment: Is this a question about how to make the function clear the `textarea` or a question about how to make your button look like a trash icon?

Comment: add the background image in the input field, if you meant that!   You can use font-awesome to make trash button, just google it font awesome css

Answer (score 1):

So no matter what you will want to have an onClick so that the DOM will know what to do when the button is clicked. What you want to do is create your button element and then use the `img` html tag inside of the button to pass through the source of a trash icon.

Kind of like this...

```
<button onClick=() => {..Do Stuff}>
  <img src='TrashCanSource.jpg' />
</button>
```

Your text area should be storing your value whether it be in the localStorage, and redux store, a database, etc.  When you hit clear you would clear that value from wherever it is being stored.